# How to select a property of an Object containing a class

Tags: javascript, tonejs

Is it possible to select a property from an object containing a class like this below?

```
//Object
const voices = {
  fmsynth: Tone.FMSynth,
  amsynth: Tone.AMSynth,
  synth: Tone.Synth
}

//my function to select the above synths
switch_synth(synth_id) {
   const synth = new Tone.PolySynth(voices[synth_id],  6).toDestination();
   console.log(voices[synth_id]);
}
```

Comment: A property can contain any value, and accessing it doesn't depend on what it contains.

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem with what you've written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, as long as you call it with the appropriate key

In your code, call `voices["fmsynth"]` or even `voices.fmsynth`, to get `Tone.FMSynth`.

So your code seems to be doing the right thing, as long as you are calling `switch_synth` with an appropriate `synth_id`, e.g.

```
switch_synth("fmsynth")
```

Are you getting an error, and if so, what error?

Comment: I am probably getting into some trouble with how the library is expecting the synth load instead of a JS object's properties way of working. So I am gonna try to edit my initial thread.